# Set Date value to hiddent input tag in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have one field "createdDate" for Student.java(entity class). I have a model attribute studRecord that have student object.

I want to set value of student createdDate field in hidden value in this way:

```
 <form:hidden path="createdDate" value="${studRecord.createdDate}"/>
```

When user clicks on submit button, I m not able to fetch its value. It is printing "null".
Kindly tell me how to set its value.

Comment: studRecord.createdDate has this value 2013-12-14 10:00:00.0

Comment: Have you checked the element that it is containing that value before you submitted the form? Or have you checked the request body?

Comment: It's easier to give you an answer if you provide the code you've trying with.

Comment: hey @sim, I think you are doing some mistake in a tittle like **hiddent**.

Answer (score 0):

sample date format in hidden type:

```
<input type="text" name="StartDate" size="16" maxlength="16"><br>

<input type="hidden" name="StartDate_required" 
        value="You must enter a start date.">

<input type="hidden" name="StartDate_date" 
        value="Please enter a valid date as the start date.">
```

And more [model](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=validateData_10.html) having in jsp.The procedure creates a simple form for entering a start date and a salary. It uses hidden fields to ensure that you enter data and that the data is in the right format.

**The hidden tag**

This tag renders an HTML 'input' tag with type 'hidden' using the bound value. To submit an unbound hidden value, use the HTML input tag with type 'hidden'.

```
<form:hidden path="house" />
```

If we choose to submit the 'house' value as a hidden one, the HTML would look like:

```
<input name="house" type="hidden" value="Gryffindor"/>
```